# How to start animation, wait for 'X' seconds and then undo animation?

Tags: wpf, wpf-animation

I have an animation that brings a text block down when I have an error that I want to display to the user.  Currently, it comes down in .5 seconds.  Is there a way to bring it down in .5 seconds, keep it there for 10 seconds, and then hide it in .5 seconds?  I found the auto reverse property, which takes care of the beginning and ending, but I have not found a way to keep the text block displayed for a specified period of time.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MessageSlide" AutoReverse="True">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MessageSlide}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: What does you animation currently look like? Include a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another KeyFrame that just holds the value:

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames ... AutoReverse="True">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50"/>
    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5.5" Value="50"/>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

You may as well just set the animation's Duration:

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames ... Duration="0:0:5.5" AutoReverse="True">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50"/>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: That works, but what exactly does that additional DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame property do?  I read on msdn that "Discrete key frames like DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame create sudden jumps between values. The animated property does not change until the key frame's key time is reached at which point the animated property goes suddenly to the target value."  So that Easing property allows the textblock to slide down with an animation of .5 seconds and the Discrete property makes it immediately go down (which does nothing because of Easing) and holds it there for the specified time before auto reversing?

Comment: As said, here it just holds the value. Of course after the easing frame has run. Didn't you try it to see what happens?

Comment: Yes it holds the value.  I also removed the easing property to see what would happen and the animation did not run at all.  That's why I didn't understand what the Discrete property was doing since the documentation made it seem as if the animation would occur immediately at the specified time.  In other words, at 5.5 seconds the text block would be visible with no Easing transitioning.